# Text not showing in textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a model with a fildValue1 parameter which has a string data type. when requested, the text can be displayed in the input tag but not in the textarea

```
<div>
    <input type="text" asp-for="fildName1" value="@Model.fildName1" placeholder="name">
    <textarea type="text" style="width: 200px" asp-for="fildValue1" placeholder="value">@Model.fildValue1</textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="fildInline1" > Inline
</div>
```

[image]

I tried different tags only works with Input tag. but i need line input capability

I have an encapsulated constructor like { get; set;} in a variable. I figured it out and it doesn't output value. When I change it to ="" it outputs the value, but now when I want to get it through form input it outputs an empty value

Comment: Hi @Yuri Chernushenko, it works fine in my project. You need check if you set the value for `fildValue1` in your backend.

Comment: I have an encapsulated constructor like { get; set;} in a variable. I figured it out and it doesn't output value. When I change it to ="" it outputs the value, but now when I want to get it through form input it outputs an empty value

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
<textarea type="text" style="width: 200px" asp-for="fildValue1" placeholder="value">@Model.fildValue1</textarea>
```

TO

```
<textarea type="text" style="width: 200px" asp-for="fildValue1" placeholder="value"></textarea>
```